# Initial values of Inkeri's primality test for Fermat numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample to the claim given below ?

First , we shall give a definition of the Inkeri's primality test for Fermat numbers :

> Fermat's number $F_m=2^{2^m}+1$ ($m \ge 2$) is prime if and only if $F_m$ divides the term $v_{2^m-2}$ of the series $v_0=8$ , $v_i=v^2_{i-1}-2$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLtTWy5uUqs7UAkm62RnFGcbnahkB2ckmRLYguz8jMSdUA8myAkrm6Rjpltr75KRplcUZAtpumNVBG29ZQE6gyM02jzNbWQKegKDOvREMJSOWmKmnCuMn5uQX5xZklQCFNawBEBiGY&lang=gp) .

Next , we shall formulate a claim :

> Let $a_n=62 a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ with $a_1=8$ and $a_2=488$ , let $b_n=482b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ with $b_1=22$ and $b_2=10582$ , then each member of the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ can be used as an initial value $v_0$ for Inkeri's test .

Union of sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A304177) .

You can calculate $a_n$ [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszW25uVKNLS1AFFGtiYWIEY2WLQ8IzMnVSPbxjZPJ9HWzEgr0Ug30dAaqDbRyBqoNNE6W1tbk5eroCgzr0QjUdMaALc6Ex0=&lang=gp) and $b_n$ [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszW25uVKMrQ1MgLRRraGBqYWIGY2WKI8IzMnVSPbxjZPJ8nWxMJIK8lIN8nQGqg-ycgaqDrJOltbW5OXq6AoM69EI0nTGgD1ahPl&lang=gp) .

P.S.

Initial values for [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) can be also obtained as the union of two recurrent sequences : $a_n=14 a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ with $a_1=4$ and $a_2=52$  , and $b_n=98b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ with $b_1=10$ and $b_2=970$ . See [A018844](https://oeis.org/A018844) .

Comment: Later posted to MO as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300638/conjectured-initial-values-of-inkeris-primality-test-for-fermat-numbers